# Update webpack 4 to webpack 5 on an existing create-react-app ejected with react-app-rewired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-5, react-app-rewired

I have an existing old react application, created with `create-react-app` and ejected with `react-app-rewired`. I'm updating the deprecated dependencies. I've already updated `react-scripts` to the current version (4.0.3) and everything works fine. But I need to update the `style-loader` lib, and this new version requires webpack 5.

The current `react-scripts` version is using webpack 4:

```
> npm ls webpack
my-app@0.1.0
└─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
  └── webpack@4.44.2
```

I found a project named `webpack-5-react-script`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-5-react-scripts. It seems what I need, but as my project was ejected using `react-app-rewired` a long time ago, I get this error when I run `npm start`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-scripts/package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/.../my-app/node_modules/react-app-rewired/scripts/utils/paths.js
- /home/../my-app/node_modules/react-app-rewired/scripts/start.js
```

What I can do? Has anybody faced this issue?

Comment: It seems that I'm not the only one with this problem: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9664#issuecomment-917260217. Maybe the best option is to wait until react-scripts 5 comes out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts

Answer (score 0):

React app rewired start, calls react-scripts start, you would need to edit react app rewired to call webpack5-react-scripts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just download react-scripts 5.0.0 into your project?

Comment: This looks more like a comment rather than a new answer.